# Get entity where one field has several values (Hibernate)

Tags: hibernate

Table. I want to get users which have firm_id = 1 and firm_id = 2 (not OR)
`user_id | firm_id`
`-----------------`
`1       |       1`
`2       |       1`
`1       |       2`

On SQL it will be : `SELECT user_id FROM table WHERE firm_id IN (1,2) GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(user_id)=2`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Zelldon How can i get users which have firm_id = 1 and firm_id = 2 via hibernate?

Comment: Hibernate for java? You can use sql queries and also HQL ?

Comment: @Zelldon Java. Use Criteria

Answer (score 1):

So if you use Hibernate with the Criterion or Criteria Api your can use also the Restriction Interface.

```
List users = sess.createCriteria(User.class)
.add( Restrictions.and(
    Restrictions.eq( "firm_id", 1 ),
    Restrictions.eq( "firm_id", 2 )
) ).list();
```

See also the documentation:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html